# Problem with re render component from every time socket send data

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, use-effect, prerender

I have a problem with the rendering in the react, when I subscribe to a socket.io event, this data coming once at 300ms (it's an array of objects). Each time the data comes from the socket, my component is rendered, whether that data is the same or not.

Here is my *socket.js* file:

```
import socketClient from "socket.io-client";

const ENDPOINT = `http://localhost:8080/?token=admin`;

export const socket = socketClient(ENDPOINT);

export const subscribeToData = (cb) => {
    socket.on(`realtime-data`, data => cb(data));
}
```

Now, here is my *App.js* file :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  subscribeToData,
} from "./utils/socketIO";

import ChildComponent from "./Components/ChildComponent/ChildComponent";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  let objectData = {};

  useEffect(() => {
    subscribeToData((socketData) => {
      setData((prevState) => {
        if (prevState !== socketData)
          return socketData
        return prevState
      });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {data.length > 0 && (
        <ChildComponent
          data={data}
        />
      )}

    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

How can I fix the problem so that when I receive new data, my child component will be rendered, but when I receive the same data, it will not be rendered?

Thank you guys, for your time.

EDIT!!!!
I make this things and work,I don't know if is the perfect solution but it work:

```
export const subscribeToData = (cb) => {
    let prevStateData = []
    socket.on(`realtime-data`, data => {
        if (JSON.stringify(prevStateData) !== 
            JSON.stringify(data)) {
            prevStateData = data
            cb(data)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: From backend, data is send at 300ms, it's an array of objects.

Comment: I try to do this thing, but I don't know if it's real good solution : 
```
let prevState= []
export const subscribeToData = (cb) => {
    socket.on(`realtime-data`, data => {
        if (JSON.stringify(prevState) !== JSON.stringify(data)) {
            prevState= data
            cb(data)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Try using setData(socketData); useState within React hooks shouldn't rerender components by itself if it passes the === comparison. By the way, why don't you just emit an event when the data changes in the backend instead of every 300ms?

Comment: @sharpness The backend is created by another company. I don't have much big influence on him.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the array of objects into a string using `JSON.stringify()` to compare the old and new state:

```js
useEffect(() => {

    subscribeToData(socketData => {
        
        let oldSocket = JSON.stringify(data)
        let newSocket = JSON.stringify(socketData)

        if(oldSocket !== newSocket)
            setData(socketData)

    })

}, [])
```

If you compare strings instead of array of objects, you can prevent React from rerendering your component.

Comment: Thank you for you're time. I make some changes and put it on my post (edited). Now work. Need to me on my subscribeToData function, not in useEffect.